# How to compute a similarity metric between two Series containing lists?

Tags: python, pandas

Having the following Series:

```
a = pd.Series([[1,2,34], [2,3], [2,3,4,5,1]], index = [1,2,3])

1         [1, 2, 34]
2             [2, 3]
3    [2, 3, 4, 5, 1]
```

and the following metric:

```
def metric(x, y):
    return len(np.intersect1d(x, y))
```

I wanna compute a similarity metric over the Series and the result should be:

```
  1  2  3
1 3  1  2
2 1  2  2 
3 2  2  5
```

So far i used this:

```
sims = a.map(lambda x: a.map(lambda y: metric(x, y)))
pd.DataFrame({k: v for k,v in sims.items()})
```

I wanna know if there is another more elegant method that can achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use `pd.concat` to join `pd.Series` objects together, it's more efficient.

```
pd.concat([a.apply(metric, args=(a.loc[y],)) for y in a.index], 1)
```